# Do you have a phrase similar to "iritating my soul"

Tags: vocabulary

Do you have a phrase or word with the following meaning?

For instance: He irritate my ***soul***( he annoy me)

updated: If we would like to say that someone has so drastically bothered me that even my soul, mind, or all of my existence is in an extraordinary bad mood- the worst mood.

Comment: How serious of an irritation is this? If someone was "irritating my soul" then I would probably need professional counseling, or maybe a priest to talk me out of murder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In English, "soul" usually occurs in contexts of a more serious nature than mere annoyance or irritation. For irritations and annoyances, we'd say:

**He gets on my nerves.**

Comment: Yes or "He is on my last nerve". Meaning you're very irritated and are probably about to yell at someone.

Answer (score 1):

There are several expressions for that, a few examples are:

> He gets on my nerves.
>
> He bothers me.
>
> He bugs me.

You can find a lot more synonyms [here](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/get-on-someone-s-nerves).

Answer (score 1):

I think we can use the following idioms:

> [He rubbed me the wrong way](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rub+the+wrong+way)

or

> [He ruffled my feathers](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ruffle+feathers)

See also usage note:

> sometimes used in the form smooth ruffled feathers (to make someone feel less annoyed or upset): The candidate went out of her way to smooth ruffled feathers.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others that if you're simply expressing annoyance, "he irritates my soul" would be too strong. However, given your update, if you want to convey that a person has upset you in a profound way, you might say "He broke my heart." However, keep in mind that this expression is frequently (although not always) used in the context of a romantic relationship.